# IS there some oprating system named SQLOS??? I have recntly encountered this jargon

Tags: sql-server, operating-system

I recently encounter a jargon SQLOS littel bit of googling took me to 
http://aureus-salah.com/2011/07/09/sql-server-operating-system/

I was wondering SQL Server is just a program on windows. Is it itself an OS????

Answer (score 1):

SQLOS is best described in Slava Oks article [SQLOS - unleashed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/02/05/367816.aspx):

> In Yukon we took idea of non-preemptive scheduling further and have
>   created new component, library, SQLOS, or sometimes referred as SOS.
>   SQLOS is a user mode operating system. It includes OS pieces such as
>   non preemptive scheduling, memory management, resource monitoring,
>   exception handling, I/O, synchronization and hosting subsystems. Keep
>   in mind SQLOS doesn’t provide OS abstraction layer to SQL Server. It
>   doesn’t warp any of Windows APIs for portability purposes. Contrary it
>   continues further binding of SQL Server to Windows by exploiting
>   scalability and performance features of the Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no OS named "SQLOS???". But there is one called "SQLOS".

It is an architectural layer inside of SQL Server. It is an implementation detail.

Comment: It provides some low-level services to other parts of SQL Server. It is undocumented. The article that you mentioned (http://aureus-salah.com/2011/07/09/sql-server-operating-system/) actually contains a good description of what it contains. It is not an operating system in the common sense. it is a library, nothing more.

Comment: It is documented! that confuse me I could not notice MS documentation on this.

Comment: @Pritesh, "undocumented" means "not officially documented by Microsoft". Community documentation is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

SQLOS is not an 'OS' in the traditional sense.  SQLOS refers to the way SQL Server operates.  You can take a look at the Microsoft Certified Master Module here: http://bit.ly/JBIprI